# Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be provided with component-wise multiplication $\cdot$ and component-wise addition $+$. Does $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,\cdot)$ form a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, field-theory

> Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be provided with component-wise multiplication $\cdot$ and component-wise addition $+$. Does $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,\cdot)$ form a field?

I would say no, because not all elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have an inverse element:

$\begin{align}x\circ x^{-1}&=e \qquad (x^{-1}:=\text{inverse element to }x)\\
(x,y)\cdot(x^{-1},y^{-1})&=(1,1)\\
(x^{-1},y^{-1})&=\left(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y}\right)| \quad\text{Equation doesn't hold for } \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ but for } \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}
\end{align}$

No inverse exists for $(0,1)$ because $x^{-1}=(\frac10,\frac11)\notin\mathbb{R}^2 \implies \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a field.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: This looks OK. In line 4 you want $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}.$

Comment: Yeah thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: In fact, as you show in line 5, the equation of line 4 does not hold for any point with $x-$ or $y-$coordinate, or both, equal to $0.$ So, the equation fails for any point on either coordinate axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof by counterexample works.

Careful though, the equation does not hold for $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash{(0,0)}$, because, as you said, $(0,1)$ is not invertible.

For every non-zero element to be invertible, you would need to exclude every pair which has a zero in it. 
So $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash{(a,b)} \text{ such that } ab = 0$. (except the pair $(0,0)$).

*Edit:* as metamorphy pointed out though, that set is not closed under addition, so not a field.

Comment: ... and after this "exclusion" it won't be closed under addition (say).

Comment: @metamorphy good point indeed, thanks, I edited the message.